# How to set negative z-index with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have two buttons, a left arrow and a right arrow to navigate through my slideshow. The slideshow has several parts. If one part ends the next button hides. But even if it's not visible it's still clickable and that messes up my code because I have a counter. To make it "unclickable" I would like to change the css via jquery to `z-index: -1;` but it doesn't work. I tried following:

```
$('#bx-next').css({"zIndex":"-1"});
```

and also:

```
$('#bx-next').css({zIndex:-1});
```

How to do it right? Didn't find anything on google - but it has to be possible, right?

Comment: It should be "z-index" and not "zIndex"... btw, just wondering why not just set the display to "none" so that your button becomes hidden and unclickable.

Comment: The hide()-function does nothing else but setting "display:none", I also tried css({"display":"none"}) - my button was invisible but still clickable. About z-index and zIndex - I made the experience that if you use the jQuery css property that all hyphenated word has to be written this way. For example margin-top becomes marginTop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
$('#bx-next').css('z-index', '-1');
```

If you want more than one, you can do this:

```
$('#bx-next').css({
  'z-index' : '-1',
  'color' : 'red',
  'background' : 'blue'
});
```

You don't need to use `{}` if you're only dealing with one element to change.

Also, if this doesn't work there's a good chance that `z-index` isn't doing anything (maybe it's not `position`'d?

**Please note:** When a css object has a `-` in it, it needs to be surrounded in quotes. `z-index` wont work, where as `'z-index'` will.

eg:

```
$('#bx-next').css(z-index, -1);     // wont work
$('#bx-next').css('z-index', '-1'); // works
```

## New answer

```
 $('#bx-next').parent().css('z-index', '-1');
```

`parent()` will get the parent element, which is what is actually changing the links.

Comment: Thx! I know that I don't need the {} I just like them. ;) Meanwhile I figured out that my code $('#bx-next').css({"zIndex":"-1"}); worked. I mean there is a z-index of -1 but the button is still clickable even if not visible and a negative z-index. I don't get it :(

Comment: Is it possible you can made a http://JsFiddle.net ? It'll be easier to look then? @user2718671

Comment: Would be too much code for a jsfiddle. But you can have a look at it here: http://flowcenter4.flowworks.de/frontend/screeningroom/vuHJUgpFHJJvdMLoVIyz_layoutpdf/8/ By using the arrow keys or the pager navigation above the slider everything works as expected but clicking on the invisible buttons with the mouse messes up everything... Don't know how to make them unclickable

Comment: Brilliant! That was the solution! Thank you soo much! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bx-next').css("z-index", "-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :-

```
$('#bx-next').css('z-index', '-1');
```

OR

```
$('#bx-next').attr('style','z-index:-1;');
```